# Wrong behavior when stopping a winapi thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

First of all I am building a user interface with MFC. Then my problem is the following I am starting a winapi thread at some point which goes well. Then when clicking in a button I want this thread to stop. For this I set up a boolean variable which I set to True and then hopefully it will break the thread loop and after a short time the thread will close. Here is a simplified version of what I am doing.

```
HANDLE LoadDataThread
DWORD LoadDataThreadId

void DialogClass::CreateThreadRP() {
    LoadDataThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, LoadData, (void*)this, 0, 
                                  &LoadDataThreadId);
}

DWORD WINAPI DialogClass::LoadData(void* lpParam) {
     DialogClass* This = (DialogClass*)lpParam;
     // Some initializations...
     for(int i=0; i<100 && !This->stopThread; i++) {
          // Operations taking some time (between 30 and 50ms)
          // Plus updating UI elements 
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Finally we create a end thread function to tell that we need to exit the loop if not finished.

```
void DialogClass::EndThreadRP() {

    stopThread = TRUE;

    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(LoadDataThread, 500);

}
```

Here the problem is that wait for single object always timeout and only then the thread exits. I increased the timeout to 1000 and even infinite but it does not change (with infinite the program freezes). It looks like the `WaitForSingleObject` stops the thread from running. Also stopThread is declared as a private bool member of the class and the thread function is defined as static function in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. As @SebastianRedl pointed out, it might come from the fact that I am directly updating the UI from this thread. By commenting these lines, `WaitForSingleObject` does not time out anymore and the thread ends correctly.

Comment: *updating UI elements* - mean send message to UI thread and **wait** for reply. so you work thread will exit only after UI thread handle this message. but he wait inside `WaitForSingleObject` and not handle any ui messages